# ASP.NET 3.5 Permissions on IIS 6

Tags: iis, permissions, web-config, asp.net-3.5

I have an asp.net page which changes passwords in the OU. Where do I set the user which actually runs my code?

In the virtual directory security settings, is it the application pool user? Or is it in Web.config? Which one of the configurations actually configures the user that runs the asp.net code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity of the user under which a web application runs is defined by the application pool which the web application uses. All of this can be seen and set in Internet Information Server (IIS) Manager.

Comment: So what the webconfig identity for?
The IIS doesn't let me set a network administrator as the user for the application pool. But to change OU passwords I need to set an OU administrator. So what can I do?

Comment: @HaimBender: Which web.config identiy? (I know there are some settings around this, but want to avoid assumptions). I've never had any problem setting IIS to any user, but for a domain user have always used a dedicated account with minimal access (but don't have a domain here now to check).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Identitiy with which a ASP.NET application is run is set in the properties for the web application.